# Finding phrases with words starting with predefined alphabets in the same order

Tags: php, regex, algorithm, search

I have a piece of very long text `$text` which is a collection of normal english sentences (for example an article from a blog)

I have an array of some reserved alphabets

```
$reserved=array("L", "N", "C");
```

I have an array of free alphabets, for example

```
$free=array("A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
```

How can I find all the phrases in this text that have words starting with the `$reserved` alphabets in the same order that they are in the array but might or might not have words starting with the alphabets in the `$free` array.

**Final Expected Correct Results**

1. Let Us Not Cheat (It has L, N,  C in the same order as in `$reserved` array and U is present in the $free array)
2. Lost our navy and all our commanders ("It again has L, N and C in the same order as in `$reserved` array with O, A, O from the `free` array)
3. Leaving Norway Chilled (L, N, C in the same order as in `$reserved` array with no words with alphabets from the `free` array)

**Incorrect Results**

1. Lets Not Cheat our Neighbors (L, N C found but extra N found while the `$reserved` array has only 3 reserved alphabets)
2. Lets Not Cheat our Friends (F is not in the `$free` or `$reserved` array)
3. Come Look at my Car (L, N, C not in the same order as in the `$reserved` array)

I know I can go through the words one at a time in a loop and then loop through all the required alphabets and optional alphabets but I think that will be a very time consuming and inefficient way of finding out the words. I am looking out for more efficient ways of solving it... perhaps with some regular expression magic or something like that.

Can you guys give me some pointers on what should be my approach to go about this problem?

I know Regular Expression, PHP and JS but am ok if the solution can be suggested in any language.

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Like going through your text, word by word with a loop and check for certain conditions?

Comment: Yes I know I can go through the words one at a time in a loop and then loop through all the required alphabets and optional alphabets but I think that will be a very time consuming and inefficient way of finding out the words. I am looking out for more efficient ways of solving it... perhaps with some regular expression magic or something like that.

Comment: Just use a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with a simple loop.

That said, you can extract the starting letters of the word, uppercase the generated string (eg: `LUNC`), then match it against `'^[AEIOU]*L[AEIOU]*N[AEIOU]*C[AEIOU]*$'`. It's easy to generate this expression. Still, I'm not sure it's worth the effort... you will end up with an uglier code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already you could use a loop. You mentioned the possibility of using a regular expression, so I've written one just to cover all bases - what worked for me was:

```
/^([aeiou]\w+\s?)*L\w+ ([aeiou]\w+\s?)*N\w+ ([aeiou]\w+\s?)*C\w+$/gim
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?360oi)

A regex like the above could be generated automatically with PHP, though whether you want something that complex is another matter! As you mentioned regex possibilities, I thought you'd like to see this anyway.